# Trig functions of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

I was studying complex numbers with the help of Boas textbook. 
    I came about certain problems, which I solved only to find
     that the answers provided in the solution manual to be different. Any help ? 
    express $sin i$ in $x+iy$ form
    since $\sin z = \frac{(e^{iz}) -(e^{-iz})}{2i}$. 
    so on substituting $i$ for $z$ I get 
    $\sin i = \frac{((ie^2)-i)}{2e}$. but the answer shown is $\frac{13}{5}$. Please help. Thank you! Also how do I write equations in a more formatted way here in math.stackexchange?

Comment: The book has an erratum.

Comment: @Dr.MV thank u for the reply. i looked upon the net for corrections and revisions for boas' mathematical methods in physical sciences. I am using the second edition, so I cant the revisions of the same. Will I have to just satisfy with the assumption that it was an error ? I have tried to solve the problem as well as I could.

Comment: Your solution looks correct although I would probably have written $\sin i=i\sinh(1)$, which is a bit more compact looking.

Comment: yes, that is right. @Dr.MV thanks again. I had to just check whether the answer was right.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Comment: As already commented by  Dr. MV, your result is perfectly correct. I really wonder how such enormous errors can appera in textboobs !

Answer (score 3):

The text book has an erratum and the solution posted in the question is correct.  We have

$$\begin{align}
\sin (i) &=\frac{e^{i(i)-}e^{-i(i)}}{2i}\\\\
&=\frac{e^{-1}-e^{1}}{2i}\\\\
&=i\frac{e^{1}-e^{-1}}{2}\\\\
&=i\sinh (1)
\end{align}$$

In fact, we can generalize this to find $\sin (iz)$

$$\begin{align}
\sin (iz) &=\frac{e^{i(iz)-}e^{-i(iz)}}{2i}\\\\
&=\frac{e^{-z}-e^{z}}{2i}\\\\
&=i\frac{e^{z}-e^{-z}}{2}\\\\
&=i\sinh (z)
\end{align}$$

Thus, for all $z$ we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sin (iz)=i\sinh(z)}$$

Comment: yes, i figured the easy way to do the question once I studied hyperbolic functions which was the following section.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Express $\sin(i)$ in the form $a+bi$:

We know the following thing:

$$a+bi=|a+bi|e^{\arg(a+bi)i}=|a+bi|(\cos(\arg(a+bi))+\sin(\arg(a+bi))i)$$

---

$$\sin(i)=$$
$$\sinh(1)i=$$
$$\left|\sinh(1)i\right|e^{\arg\left(\sinh(1)i\right)i}=$$
$$\sqrt{\Re(\sinh(1)i)^2+\Im(\sinh(1)i)^2}e^{\arg\left(\sinh(1)i\right)i}=$$
$$\sqrt{0^2+\sinh(1)^2}e^{\arg\left(\sinh(1)i\right)i}=$$
$$\sqrt{\sinh(1)^2}e^{\arg\left(\sinh(1)i\right)i}=$$
$$\sinh(1)e^{\arg\left(\sinh(1)i\right)i}=$$
$$\sinh(1)e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}=$$
$$\sinh(1)\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)i\right)=$$
$$\sinh(1)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\sinh(1)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)i=$$
$$\sinh(1)\cdot 0+\sinh(1)\cdot 1i=$$
$$\sinh(1)\cdot 1i=$$
$$\sinh(1)i$$

So $\sin(i)$ expressed in the form $a+bi$ gives us: $0+\sinh(1)i$

Comment: thanks for the reply @Jan Eerland. I dont quite understand how in the first statement you equated sin i to sinhi. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @AnandTR you're welcome! $\sin(i)=\sinh(1)i$